# Mounting NFS share from OpenSolaris on Linux

Tags: permissions, solaris, nfs, file-sharing, opensolaris

I have an OpenSolaris server (snv_101b) serving files via NFS.  Everything works fine when mounting the shares on ESXi or OS X, but when I mount from Linux (CentOS 5.2) everything is mounted as nobody:nobody with 755 permissions.  This means that the user cannot make any changes.  How do I mount the share correctly?

The directory was shared with:

`# zfs set sharenfs=on /tank/share`

And is mounted with:

`# mount -t nfs4 server:/tank/share /mountpoint`

Comment: Can I ask what is driving the preference for NFSv4?

Comment: Mainly because newer generally equals better.  I'm not really very experienced with NFS.  However, the same problem happens with nfs3.

Answer (score 3):

NFSv4 does user@DOMAIN lookups (not simple UID/GID enforcement like NFSv3) so you need to have the same authentication database (files, LDAP, whatever) on both systems. With v3 all you need is to have the same UID/GID as the file...not necessarily the same username. If you don't need any of the features of v4, I'd recommend going with v3 on Linux. Historically, Linux has had a pretty flaky v4 implementation.

Answer (score 0):

What version of NFS are you running client-side?  Has CentOS 5.2 gotten around to NFSv4?  Many distros are supporting NFSv3.

Comment: Pretty sure it's at 4.  I'm sure it'd complain otherwise.  The same thing happens if I use "mount -t nfs"

Comment: Initial support for NFSv4 was added with RHEL4/CentOS 4.x, although I wouldn't recommend using it.  I had some stability issues with it.

With RHEL5.x/CentOS 5.x NFSv4 is solid and works quite well.

Comment: Yep, I'm using CentOS 5.2, as described in the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Be careful if running CentOS 5.2 or the RHEL equal on the client side. There is a kernel/nfs-utils bug that will cause the system to hang.